# Android NullPointerException Handling

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, crash, null

My Android application keeps crashing when i click on Fish option and nothing is inserted in the settings activity it's a null pointer exception and i tried to handle it but no result so here is my code 
SelectPetsScreen Acivity

```
package com.set.petshome;
public class SelectPetsScreen extends Activity  {
    fishtank ii=new fishtank();
    ImageButton fButton,sButton,tButton;
    Button chButton,setsButton;
      private MediaPlayer mp0,mp1;
      public String value;
      final Context context = this;
      String numvalue;
    FirstSSettings testObj= new FirstSSettings();
        //public String chnumber;// recipient's mobile number
        public String num;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectscreen);
                    //menu startup sound Code
      mp0=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.menu);             
        mp0.start();  

        //End Menu Sound Code

        //Settings Button Start
        setsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsb);
        setsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Voice
                    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);               
                    mp1.start();            
                    //End Voice
                    //Starting a new Intent

                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);

                }
            });     

        //Settings Button End


        //Second Ch No.Button Start
            chButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changebutton);    
            // add button listener
                    chButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            // custom dialog
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mycustom);
                            dialog.setTitle("Change Number");

                            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                            TextView current = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cn);
                            current.setText("Current Number:");
                        //current.setText("Current Number:");
                        TextView et11 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et1);
                        //et11.setKeyListener(null);

                        et11.setText(FirstSSettings.getUserNumber());

                        TextView newnum = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nn);          
                        newnum.setText("New Number:");
                        TextView et22 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et2);
                        et22.setText("");






                        //  ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                            //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changebutton);
                            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    TextView et22 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et2);
                                    numvalue = et22.getText().toString();
                                    FirstSSettings.setNumber(numvalue); 



                      //Button Fishtank Listener Start


                        fButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                          //Listening to button event

                           fButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               Boolean wifi,gsm;
                               String x,y;
                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                    num=FirstSSettings.UserNumber;
                                    //Voice
                                    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);               
                                    mp1.start();            
                                    //End Voice

                                    //String s = FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString();
                                    //String d = FirstSSettings.UserWifi.toString();
                                    //if(s.equals("false")&& d.equals("false"))
                                    FirstSSettings a=new FirstSSettings();
                                try { Log.v(FirstSSettings.UserGSM == null ? "UserGSM is Null object": "Not Null object", ""); 
                                x=FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString();
                                y=FirstSSettings.UserWifi.toString(); 
                                } 
                                catch(Exception e) 
                                { 
                                Log.v("Catch NullPointerException and missed all the fun",""); 
                                e.printStackTrace(); 
                                } 
                                Log.v(x == null ? "NullPointerException after this line": "Everything is allright","");



                             //  if();{y="false";}



                                if(x.equals("false")&&(y.equals("false")))
                                {
                                    {

                                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.check_dialog);
                                        dialog.setTitle("Settings Alert");
                                        TextView plCheck = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.plCheck);
                                        plCheck.setText("Check Your Connection Settings");

                                        Button okBut = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.okBut);
                                        //Temp Start

                                        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                                    okBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {                                               
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                try
                                                {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.getUserNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                                catch (Exception e)
                                                {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.class);
                                                startActivity(nextScreen3);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        dialog.show();



                                        //Temp End




                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fishtank.class);
                                        startActivity(nextScreen);  
                                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.UserWifi.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    }


                                    //Starting a new Intent
                    /*               
                     testObj =new FirstSSettings();

                                    if(testObj.getUserGSM()==false&&testObj.getUserWifi()==false)
                                    {

                                        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fishtank.class);
                                        startActivity(nextScreen);   
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    {                                       
                                            Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), fishtank.class);
                                            startActivity(nextScreen1);

                                    }                        
                                    */
                                }

                                             });
                        //Button Fishtank Listener End

                           //Button Cats Listener Start

                            sButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

                              //Listening to button event
                               sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                        //Voice
                                        final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);             
                                        mp1.start();            
                                        //End Voice
                                        //Starting a new Intent
                                        Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Csoon.class);
                                        startActivity(nextScreen2);

                                    }
                                });     
                            //Button Cats Listener End
                             //Button Dogs Listener Start

                                tButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

                                  //Listening to button event
                                   tButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                            //Voice
                                            final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.menu);             
                                            mp1.start();            
                                            //End Voice
                                            //Starting a new Intent
                                            Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dsoon.class);
                                            startActivity(nextScreen3);

                                        }
                                    });}        
                                //Button Dogs Listener End  



                    //Menu handle
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_screen, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
              switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case R.id.ChangeColor:
                        // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                  Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstSSettings.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen3);
                         return true;   

              case R.id.phoneInformation:
                         // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                        Intent nextScreen4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Verify.class);
                        startActivity(nextScreen4);
                         return true;

               case R.id.callInfo:
                //   startActivity(new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).setData(getIntent().getData()));                        // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                                              return true;

              case R.id.email:
                                             // write code to execute when clicked on this option
                                               return true;

                default:
                                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }



    }
```

FirstSSettings Activity

```
package com.set.petshome;



public class FirstSSettings extends Activity {
Button loginButton,saveButton,cancelButton;
//CheckBox gsmbox,wifibox;
public static  Boolean UserGSM;
public  static Boolean UserWifi;

public  static String UserNumber;
TextView nfield ;
TextView e_num;
CheckBox wifibox;
CheckBox gsmbox ;
TextView wifiuser,wifipass,wifi_uan,wifi_pan;
String wifi_u,wifi_p;

//login var
EditText u,p;
TextView res;
String result;
String x="mobile";
Thread runOnUiThread;
InetAddress address;


    public  static void setNumber(String a)
    {

        UserNumber=a;       
    }
    public Boolean getUserGSM()
    {
        return UserGSM;
    }
    public Boolean getUserWifi()
    {
        return UserWifi;
    }
    public static String getUserNumber()
    {
        return UserNumber;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_ssettings);



        wifiuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiuser);
        wifi_uan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_uan);
        wifipass=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifipass);
        wifi_pan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_pan);  
        wifibox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Wifi);        
        nfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ntxtfield);
        res=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

        nfield.setText(UserNumber);


        wifibox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Wifi);      
          //Listening to button event
        //Wifi CheckbBox onClickListener start
        //Temp

        wifibox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (wifibox.isChecked())
                    {
                        NetworkInfo xWifi;
                        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        xWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                        if (xWifi.isConnected()) {
                            // Do whatever
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            callCheck();                                

                        }      
                    }else{

                    }

            }

        });

            //testing if it is checked or unchecked



           //Wifi Checkbox onClickListener end
         //Wifi CheckbBox onCheckedChange start
        wifibox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {           
        //recording the click of the checkbox
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {


            wifiuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiuser);
            wifi_uan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_uan);
            wifi_u=wifi_uan.getText().toString();

            wifipass=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifipass);
            wifi_pan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_pan);
             wifi_p=wifi_pan.getText().toString();
            //testing if it is checked or unchecked
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                //if it is check
                 wifiuser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 wifi_uan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 wifipass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 wifi_pan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 res.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                wifiuser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 wifi_uan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 wifipass.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 wifi_pan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 res.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
        });

        //Wifi CheckBox end 

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }); 

        //GSM CheckbBox start

                gsmbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.GSM);
                gsmbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {

                //recording the click of the checkbox
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    nfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ntxtfield);
                    e_num=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.e_num);

                    //testing if it is checked or unchecked
                    if ( isChecked )
                    {
                        //if it is check
                         nfield.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        e_num.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                     nfield.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   e_num.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                    }

                }
                });

                //GSM CheckBox end 



        //login Button start
                loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

                loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try
                        {
                        wifibox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Wifi);
                        gsmbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.GSM);

                        UserGSM=gsmbox.isChecked();
                        UserWifi=wifibox.isChecked();


                        wifi_u=wifi_uan.getText().toString();
                        wifi_p=wifi_pan.getText().toString();

                        u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wifi_uan);
                        p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wifi_pan);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), u.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(u.getText().toString(),p.getText().toString());
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });

            //login Button end



        //Save Button Start
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        //Temp obj

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 nfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ntxtfield);
                 //wifibox= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Wifi);
                 //gsmbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.GSM);

                 setNumber(nfield.getText().toString());
                    //UserGSM=gsmbox.isChecked();
                    //UserWifi=wifibox.isChecked();


                    //Starting a new Intent
                    //wifi_u=wifi_uan.getText().toString();

                    //wifi_p=wifi_pan.getText().toString();

                    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectPetsScreen.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen);

                    //setDefaults();

                try
                {                   
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), UserNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), UserGSM.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), UserWifi.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                }

            });     


        //Save button End 



        //Cancel button Start
      cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    //Starting a new Intent
                    Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectPetsScreen.class);
                    startActivity(nextScreen2);

                }
            });     

        //Cancel Button End 

    }


}
```

Logcat

```
    12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at com.set.petshome.SelectPetsScreen$4.onClick(SelectPetsScreen.java:211)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-04 21:04:05.041: E/AndroidRuntime(2789):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 192 `SelectPetsScreen.java`?

Comment: Please only include the _relevant_ code. You have hundreds of lines of code that make it very difficult (and time consuming) to find the problem. Just the method or a handful of the lines surrounding the NullPointerException should be sufficient.

Comment: if(x.equals("false")&&(y.equals("false")))>>X refers to UserGSM and Y refers to UserWifi

Comment: @user1928775 x and y are null.

Comment: Rahunandan when you take a look at the code you'll see that i'm 
assigning them to 
 x=FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString();
  y=FirstSSettings.UserWifi.toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static  Boolean UserGSM;// its an Object not primitive, so by default it is null
public  static Boolean UserWifi;//same thing
```

This variables can be never initialized and holds null. So x and y are null, because FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString() are catched in try block as NullPointerException and leaves x equals to null.

Try this:

```
...
FirstSSettings a=new FirstSSettings();
try {   
    Log.v(FirstSettings.UserGSM == null ? "UserGSM is Null object": "Not Null object");
    x=FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString();
    y=FirstSSettings.UserWifi.toString();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.v("Catch NullPointerException and missed all the fun");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.v(x == null ? "NullPointerException after this line": "Everything is allright");
if(x.equals("false")&&(y.equals("false")))
...
```

To prevent NullPointerException just initialize Booleans

```
...
public class FirstSSettings extends Activity {
Button loginButton,saveButton,cancelButton;
//CheckBox gsmbox,wifibox;
public static  Boolean UserGSM = false;// or true based on your needs
public  static Boolean UserWifi = false;// or true based on your needs
...
```

Comment: I hope its obfuscated code, cause it's almost unreadable. Here is some code style guidelines for android - http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean please can you give an example ? thanks

Comment: I suppose problem is in empty FirstSettings.UserGSM variable. Try to log your result with code given above

Comment: still NullPointerException in the same line post will be updated in seconds(Post Updated)

Comment: the problem is initializing the variables doesn't work with my needs :D

Comment: i'm trying to find a solution that doesn't affect the values of GSM and Wifi and prevent the NullPointerException

Comment: Easiest way to use try catch, but it will add more bad code here. So handle this situation with "if (x==null || y==null) {//do your stuff here, you can't avoid this state} else {//do all you old code here}".

Comment: And, please, never do this again: x=FirstSSettings.UserGSM.toString(); x.equals("false"); Don't waste someones' CPU time it's priceless ;)